# Ajax using in mootools to load file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a problem with ajax in mootools. Is it possible to load some content same as in jQuery in mootools becouse i cant find anything about ajax in mootools. My request is simple , its look like that. Can some1 help me?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
var json = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'url': '/a/b/c.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) { 
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
//////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Please go through the mootools documentation. Ref - http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Request/Request

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'fileName.php', // here or in the form html tag "action="fileName.php"
    method: 'get',       //or post
    onRequest: function(){
        myElement.set('text', 'loading...');
    },
    onSuccess: function(responseText){
        myElement.set('text', responseText);
    },
    onFailure: function(){
        myElement.set('text', 'Sorry, your request failed :(');
    }
});
```

for more details you see this :  [mootools class:Request](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Request/Request)